# Узна́ет или узнаёт?

Tags: орфография, е-или-ё, спряжение

В каких случаях правильно писать «узна́ет», а в каких «узна**ё**т»?

Есть предположение, что «узна́ет» употребляется в будущем времени, а «узна**ё**т» в прошедшем, но я не уверен точно...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**узна́ть**](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C)
Глагол, совершенный вид, переходный;
**узна́ет** — *3 л., ед. ч., будущее время*. **Он меня ещё узнает!**

*...она никогда не узнает всего — даже половины; не узнает, как страстно он жаждал услышать звук ее голоса...* (Д. О. Кервуд)

[**узнава́ть**](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C)
Глагол, несовершенный вид, переходный;
**узнаёт** — *3л., ед. ч., настоящее время.* **Он узнаёт меня по шагам и дыханию.**

*Ляля, когда узнаёт из космоса новости про котов, всегда радуется* (Слава Сэ).

Особенности значения и употребления глаголов можно посмотреть в словаре Д. В. Дмитриева: ([узнать / узна́ет](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dmitriev/5561)) и ([узнавать / узнаёт](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dmitriev/5560/%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C)).